# Waiting for a prefetch to complete

Tags: performance, x86, intel, prefetch, amd-processor

As far as I know, on both recent AMD and Intel chips, `prefetch` instructions can retire before the associated data arrives. That is, unlike loads, retirement doesn't depend on the arrival of the associated data in the requested cache level<sup>1</sup>.

Assuming I issue a series of prefetch instructions and now I want to wait for the data to arrive before proceeding, is there any way to do it? It doesn't seem like `lfence` will work since the instruction can retire even if the data hasn't arrived.

---

<sup>1</sup> There does seem to be a significant difference relating to how Intel and AMD chips handle *execution* of prefetch instructions: Intel will always execute the prefetch instruction, and so will block if resources (such as fill buffers) are not available. AMD chips on the other hand, seem to only execute the prefetch instruction if resources are available: otherwise, the prefetch may simply be dropped. Both strategies have their merits depending on the code and access pattern.

Comment: Are there any constraints or conditions on the way to achieve this? Because you could just loop for a couple thousand cycles after issuing the prefetch.

Comment: @HadiBrais - not particularly. That's certainly one solution, but has some hard questions like it's hard to know how many cycles to loop for (maybe 10,000 is enough? I don't actually know if it is in the possible presence of things like NVRAM, etc). So better answers are appreciated, but that at least sets a baseline for what can work.